# How to make a view fit a layout?

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a main layout in which i'm adding dynamic view inflated, i do this add in scale with the main layout but in some cases the view exceeds the mainl layout height.How can i tell them to stick to the layout height and not cross over?

Thank you

Comment: Any particular reason you are trying to create your view outside of xml?

Comment: double n4 =DyL.getHeight()/100;
double n3 =(taille/pension_n)*100;
int n1 =(int) (n3*n4);      LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, n1);

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the code, so that I can help you by analyzing it. Try using proper LayoutParams. why do you want to add View dynamically. If you can make it in XML, make it!

Comment: My view is an xml file inflated and added to a layout 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_add,DyL,false);
the scale of the view is changed dynamically in relation with the layout scale but it seems that the results are not exact otherwhise it doesn't cross over the layout parent